# Checking odd/even numbers and changing outputs on number size

Tags: python, numbers

I have a couple of problems to solve for an assignment, and am a bit stuck.
The question is to write a program that gets the user to input an odd number (check it's odd), then print an upside down pyramid of stars based on the size of the input.

For example, if you enter 5, it comes up with

```
*****
 ***
  *
```

My problem is therefore two-fold.

1) How do I check if it's even or odd? I tried `if number/2 == int` in the hope that it might do something, and the internet tells me to do `if number%2==0`, but that doesn't work.

2) How do I change the asterisks in the middle of each line?

Any help with either problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if number%2==0` is the correct way and should work. For your second question, see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: What doesn't work?  You should post the error message you see when it doesn't work -- That will help us to figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: When you say `if number % 2 == 0` doesn't work, what do you mean?

Comment: To print a chain of 5 (or whatever number) stars, do `print '*' * 5`.

Comment: (Can't put this in codeblocks, sorry) Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    if number%2==0:
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @keirbtre That's telling you that your `number` is a string...

Comment: Aha, thanks. I did an input() not int(input())

Comment: @keirbtre: Do you understand why `number%2==0` works, or even what `number%2` means? If not, you may know the same operation as `mod` from other contexts. If not, you should look up the `%` or "modulo" operator so you're actually learning something rather than just using random internet magic.

Comment: This `sys.stdout.write('*') * 5` doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @keirbtre you can check out my answer it prints the pattern if it is odd but there is one problem in my answer that if doesn't return something instead of returning it prints the pattern so you can directly use the function

Answer (score 96):

Giving you the complete answer would have no point at all since this is homework, so here are a few pointers :

**Even or Odd**:

```
number % 2 == 0
```

definitely is a very good way to find whether your number is even.

In case you do not know `%`, this does modulo which is here the remainder of the division of `number` by `2`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

**Printing the pyramid**:

First advice: In order to print `*****`, you can do `print "*" * 5`.

Second advice: In order to center the asterisks, you need to find out how many spaces to write before the asterisks. Then you can print a bunch of spaces and asterisks with `print " "*1 + "*"*3`

Comment: Or you can just let Python center it, eg: `'{: ^6}'.format('*' * 3 )`

Comment: @NullUserException depending on taste - and a bit clearer (IMHO) `('*' * 3).center(5)`

Comment: Both look great ! But this is probably not the first solution that comes to mind when you are just beginning to learn Python. :-)

Comment: Re. speed (see Bill H's answer and lorenzocastillo's comment below), on a "modern" machine, the modulo method was 0.1198/0.1123 = 1.067 or about 7% faster.  IMO, the modulo method is more readable so is well worth the slight speed penalty.

Answer (score 24):

The modulo 2 solutions with %2 is good, but that requires a division and a subtraction.  Because computers use binary arithmetic, a much more efficient solution is:

```
# This first solution does not produce a Boolean value. 
is_odd_if_zero = value & 1

# or

is_odd = (value & 1) == 1

# or

is_even = (value & 1) == 0
```

Comment: I looked at timeit.Timer() to see how much of a difference, if any, does that make, and there is a (less than one order of magnitude) difference on my machine. Running it with value = sys.maxsize, 1000000 times, the difference between your method and the modulo method was roughly 0.07 seconds, in favor of your method.

Comment: But still good to know, especially when dealing with large data sets and performing multiple modulo operations per datum. Also, good to know for anyone who's programming on old, or slow hardware archtecture.
This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: A good compiler should know that `value mod 2 == 0` should evaluate to a check of the LSB in machine code, shouldn"t it?

Comment: @Jan: Python doesn't have a compiler nor an optimizer. This will make a difference.

Comment: Regarding %timeit result it seems to be exactly the same. I think if you repeat the test with 1000000 times, you might get an opposite result. It also seems that the modulo method is far more intuitive and closer to typical high-level programming workflow.

Comment: `timeit` says that modulo is faster, actually.  [Python does have an optimizer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/peephole.c)

Comment: @endolith: Python does have an optimizer but it doesn't optimize remainder (or division) by a constant. However, CPython does have a fast path for computing `%` on "short" integers, but not for bitwise operators. So `v%2` is faster than `v&1` for integers up to 30 bits (on a 64-bit system) and slower for longer integers.

Answer (score 14):

A few of the solutions here reference the time taken for various "is even" operations, specifically `n % 2` vs `n & 1`,  without systematically checking how this varies with the size of `n`, which turns out to be predictive of speed.

The short answer is that if you're using reasonably sized numbers, [normally < 1e9](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/longintrepr.h), it doesn't make much difference.  If you're using larger numbers then you probably want to be using the bitwise operator.

Here's a plot to demonstrate what's going on (with Python 3.7.3, under Linux 5.1.2):

[image: python3.7 benchmark]

Basically as you hit "arbitrary precision" longs things get progressively slower for modulus, while remaining constant for the bitwise op.  Also, note the `10**-7` multiplier on this, i.e. I can do ~30 million (small integer) checks per second.

Here's the same plot for Python 2.7.16:

[image: python2.7 benchmark]

which shows the optimisation that's gone into newer versions of Python.

I've only got these versions of Python on my machine, but could rerun for other versions of there's interest.  There are 51 `n`s between 1 and 1e100 (evenly spaced on a log scale), for each point I do the equivalent of:

```
timeit('n % 2', f'n={n}', number=niter)
```

where `niter` is calculated to make `timeit` take ~0.1 seconds, and this is repeated 5 times.  The slightly awkward handling of `n` is to make sure we're not also benchmarking global variable lookup, which is slower than local variables.  The mean of these values are used to draw the line, and the individual values are drawn as points.

Comment: I had no idea this is insanely fast

Comment: @SARose Python is still about 30 times slower than optimal/compiled code, but modern CPUs are fast!

Answer (score 9):

Simple but yet fast:

```
>>> def is_odd(a):
...     return bool(a - ((a>>1)<<1))
...
>>> print(is_odd(13))
True
>>> print(is_odd(12))
False
>>>
```

Or even simpler:

```
>>> def is_odd(a):
...   return bool(a & 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

1) How do I check if it's even or odd? I tried "if number/2 == int" in the hope that it might do something, and the internet tells me to do "if number%2==0", but that doesn't work.

```
def isEven(number):
        return number % 2 == 0
```

Comment: @NullUserException Wow, didn't even realize I had that..  :O Thanks for pointing it out/shaming me.

Comment: You just repeated exactly what he said he already tried, `if number%2==0`, except wrapped in a function and with more whitespace. How is that going to solve his problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
if number%2==0
```

will tell you that it's even. So odd numbers would be the else statement there. The "%" is the mod sign which returns the remainder after dividing. So essentially we're saying if the number is divisible by two we can safely assume it's even. Otherwise it's odd (it's a perfect correlation!)

As for the asterisk placing you want to prepend the asterisks with the number of spaces correlated to the line it's on. In your example

```
***** line 0
***   line 1
*     line 2
```

We'll want to space accordingly

```
0*****
01***
012*
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but honestly I don't think "study harder" is really appropriate, considering we only started learning about programming a few weeks ago, and have 1 lesson a week.

Comment: I removed the comment because I'm certainly not the type of person who tries to be rude. But this problem isn't about programming skills, it's about identifying patterns and applying them. For example ho numbers divisible by 2 are even, not odd.

Comment: I stand by my statement. These are simple problems. I applaud you for speaking with professionals when you need help, it's not something you should shy away from, but at this level you should really be speaking with your teacher, classmates, or a tutor. Checkout codeschool.com or buy an O'Reily book (always on sale for the holidays) and read through it.

Answer (score 3):

```
la = lambda x : "even" if not x % 2 else "odd"
```

Comment: Why do we need the negation part? Should be shorter with `la = lambda x : "odd" if x % 2 else "even"`

Answer (score 3):

I guess the easiest and most basic way is this

```
import math

number = int (input ('Enter number: '))

if number % 2 == 0 and number != 0:
    print ('Even number')
elif number == 0:
    print ('Zero is neither even, nor odd.')
else:
    print ('Odd number')
```

Just basic conditions and math. It also minds zero, which is neither even, nor odd and you give any number you want by input so it's very variable.

Comment: Zero is even. 0 = 0 x 2.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the printout, here's how I would do it using the [Format Specification Mini Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) (section: *Aligning the text and specifying a width*):

Once you have your length, say `length = 11`:

```
rowstring = '{{: ^{length:d}}}'.format(length = length) # center aligned, space-padded format string of length <length>
for i in xrange(length, 0, -2): # iterate from top to bottom with step size 2
    print rowstring.format( '*' * i )
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways to check if an int value is odd or even.
I'll show you the two main ways:

```
number = 5

def best_way(number):
    if number%2==0:
        print "even"
    else:
        print "odd"

def binary_way(number):
    if str(bin(number))[len(bin(number))-1]=='0':
        print "even"
    else:
        print "odd"
best_way(number)
binary_way(number)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
def is_even(n):
    r=n/2.0
    return True if r==int(r) else False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    n = float(input('odd:'))
    while n % 2 == 0:
        #if n % 2 == 1: No need for these lines as if it were true the while loop would not have been entered.
            #break not required as the while condition will break loop
        n = float(input('odd:'))


    for i in range(int((n+1)/2)):
        print(' '*i+'*'*int((n-2*i))+' '*i)

main()
```

`#1st part ensures that it is an odd number that was entered.2nd part does the printing of triangular`

Comment: Can you explain why this code solves the OP's problem?

Comment: 1st part ensures that it is an odd number that was entered.2nd part does the printing of triangular.

Comment: Edit that into your answer please

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Instruction**
*Given an integer, `n`, performing the following conditional actions:*

- If n is odd, print Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
- If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

```py
import math
n = int(input())

if n % 2 ==1:
    print("Weird")
elif n % 2==0 and n in range(2,6):
    print("Not Weird")
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6,21):
    print("Weird")
elif n % 2==0 and n>20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple code. You can try it and grab the knowledge easily.

```
n = int(input('Enter integer : '))
    if n % 2 == 3`8huhubuiiujji`:
        print('digit entered is ODD')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and 2 < n < 5:
        print('EVEN AND in between [2,5]')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and 6 < n < 20:
        print('EVEN and in between [6,20]')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
       print('Even and greater than 20')
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Modulus method is the usual method. We can also do this to check if odd or even:

```
def f(a):
    if (a//2)*2 == a:
        return 'even'
    else:
        return 'odd'
```

Integer division by 2 followed by multiplication by two.

Answer (score 0):

My solution basically we have two string and with the & we get the right index:

```
res = ["Even", "Odd"]
print(res[x & 1])
```

Please note that it seems slower than other alternatives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math
import random
from timeit import timeit

res = ["Even", "Odd"]

def foo(x):
    return res[x & 1]

def bar(x):
    if x & 1:
        return "Odd"
    return "Even"

la = lambda x : "Even" if not x % 2 else "Odd"

iter = 10000000

time = timeit('bar(random.randint(1, 1000))', "from __main__ import bar, random", number=iter)
print(time)
time = timeit('la(random.randint(1, 1000))', "from __main__ import la, random", number=iter)
print(time)
time = timeit('foo(random.randint(1, 1000))', "from __main__ import foo, random", number=iter)
print(time)
```

output:
8.05739480999182
8.170479692984372
8.892275177990086

Answer (score 0):

**1. another odd testing function**

Ok, the assignment was handed in 8+ years ago, but here is another solution based on bit shifting operations:

```
def isodd(i):
    return(bool(i>>0&1))
```

testing gives:

```
>>> isodd(2)
False
>>> isodd(3)
True
>>> isodd(4)
False
```

**2. Nearest Odd number alternative approach**

However, instead of a code that says "give me this precise input (an integer odd number) or otherwise I won't do anything" I also like robust codes that say, "give me a number, any number, and I'll give you the nearest pyramid to that number".

In that case this function is helpful, and gives you the nearest odd (e.g. any number f such that 6<=f<8 is set to 7 and so on.)

```
def nearodd(f):
    return int(f/2)*2+1
```

Example output:

```
nearodd(4.9)
5

nearodd(7.2)
7

nearodd(8)
9
```

Answer (score 0):

This the function

```
def oddOrEven(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        print("even")

    else: 
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(i+1):
                print(" ", end="")
            for m in range(num-i, 0, -1):
                print("* ", end="")
            print()
```

but there is a catch because it is almost impossible to return a pattern so we have to print instead of return it then use it directly `oddOrEven(5)` will print:

```
 * * * * *
  * * * *
   * * *
    * *
     *
```

Answer (score 0):

Determining even/odd:

```
is_odd = num & 1

is_even = (num & 1) == 0  # slowly: bitwise and number comparison 
is_even = (num & 1) is 0  # faster: bitwise and pointer comparsion
is_even = ~num & 1        # fastest: two bitwise operations
```

Using `is` is faster than the comparisons with double equals, but negation with `~` is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple lambda function that I really like which is:

```py
(lambda x: x % 2 and 'odd' or 'even')
```