# Python Modulo TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to create simple code to test if number is odd or even.
I am using `Python 2.7.3`.

```
def oddoreven(a):
    try: int(a)
    except: return "Error"
    if a%2==0: return 1
    else: return 0
```

Instead the code fails with error: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.` The error points to the line beginning with `if a%2==0...`.

While researching this problem I found examples indicating that code like this should work. For example answers to this question offer similar code as solution: [python - checking odd/even numbers and changing outputs on number size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636640/python-checking-odd-even-numbers-and-changing-outputs-on-number-size)

So what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `int(a)` doesn't do anything to `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you first test if `a` can be converted to an `int` (which is fine), but then you ignore this test and keep going with the `string` you provided in argument.

Python is a **dynamically typed language**, but also **strongly typed**, which means you can change the type of a variable after it's been declared, but this change has to be explicit ([more about this here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language)).

In your case, it means you can't do `if a % 2 == 0` if `a` is a string.

You could do this for instance:

```
def oddoreven(a):
    try:
        my_int = int(a)
    except TypeError:
        return "The argument provided could not be converted into an int"
    if my_int % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

the `int` function doesn't change the `a` in-place, you need to assign it to `a` :

```
>>> def oddoreven(a):
...     try: a=int(a)
...     except: return "Error"
...     if a%2==0: return 1
...     else: return 0 
... 
>>> oddoreven('2')
1
>>> oddoreven('5')
0
>>> oddoreven('a')
'Error'
```

Answer (score 1):

As user2357112 stated. (int)a does not convert a to a int. so when you check its modulus you still must convert it.

```
def oddoreven(a):
    try: int(a)
    except: return "Error"
    if int(a)%2==0: return 1
    else: return 0

print oddoreven(32)
```

works fine.

As a side note, catching any exception is generally frowned upon. You may want to narrow it down like:

```
def oddoreven(a):
    try: int(a)
    except TypeError: return "Error"
    if int(a)%2==0: return 1
    else: return 0

print oddoreven(32)
```