# How do I return a boolean value after I've carried out a operation in a functions by using a parameter?

Tags: function, python-3.x, boolean

What I believe to have here is a simple syntax error but unfortunately it has stumped my nooby mind. I have googled but had no results, I am looking to return true if the value is even and then false if the value is odd. Thanks!

```
x = 20

def MyEven(x):

    if x / 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    return x
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - checking odd/even numbers and changing outputs on number size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636640/python-checking-odd-even-numbers-and-changing-outputs-on-number-size)

Answer (score 0):

Generally there's no reason to `return x` unless the situation is more complex than this. If you only want to know if x is even, your code is fine except for two things: `return x` at the end, and the actual even check. `x / 2` will simply return x divided by 2; for `x = 20`, this will return `10`. What you want is `x % 10`; the `%` operator returns the remainder of division. If `x` is even, it returns `0`; else, it returns `1`.

However- if, for some reason, it is vital to your program that you `return x` at the end of the function, I would recommend packing your values into a tuple:

```
x = 20

def MyEven(x):
    result = False # Will remain False if x isn't even
    if x % 2 == 0:
        result =  True
    return (x, result)
```

This will return a tuple whose first value is the passed `x` and the second is `True` or `False` depending on whether `x` is even.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
def is_even(num):
    return num%2==0
```

this will return *True* if **num** is divisible by 2 (if it is even)