# How to make a list of N consecutive odd numbers starting from 1

Tags: python

I need to write a function that generates a list of n odd numbers, starting at 1. If input is 12, output should be `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]`. If input is `10`, output should be `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]`

Comment: Do you know about the [modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python)?

Comment: Hint: what will be the last item of a list of *n* odd elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - checking odd/even numbers and changing outputs on number size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636640/python-checking-odd-even-numbers-and-changing-outputs-on-number-size)

Comment: _I don't even know if I'm going to right direction_ To start, does the code work, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost..

```
def odd(n):
    nums = []
    for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):
        nums.append(i)
    return nums
```

we know that every other number is odd, so we have to "count" up to `2*n` to include all of them. The `range` function takes a third argument that indicates how many elements to skip in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

```
def odd(n):
    return list(range(1, 2*n, 2))

print(odd(10))
print(odd(12))
```

The output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]                                                                                                                           
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code with `list comprehenssion` :-

```
def odd(n):
    return [num for num in range(1, n*2+1,2)]
odd(10)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(..)` can take a third parameter that is the `step` the amount the value increments each iteration. The last item of a list with the first *n* odd elements, is *2×n-1*, so we can write this as:

```
def odd(n):
    return list(range(1, 2*n, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
def odd(n):
    return list(range(1, n * 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
def odd(n):
   return np.arange(1, 2*n, 2)


odd(10) -> array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
odd(12) -> array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23])
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

```
import numpy as np

def odd(n):
   return np.arange(1,n*2,2)
```

Comment: Code only answers can be improved by adding some explanation to it. Please take some time to explain what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also:-

```
def odd(n):
    nums = []
    for i in range(1, n*2+1):
        if i%2==0:
            pass
        else:
            nums.append(i)
    return nums
odd(10)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering a question, it’s always great to add some explanation so the OP can learn something from your code.

Comment: @trotta Ok I will

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(n):
    return[i for i in range(1,n*2,2)]
```

or

```
def E(n):
    list=[]
    list.extend(i for i in range(1,2*n,2))
    return(list)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. While code-only answers may answer the question and fix OP's problem, adding an explanation of _why_ it works will significantly improve your answers. Also, if you're reanimating such an old, inactive question, your answer needs to add something significant to what's already been said by the other answers. That isn't the case here because your answer is essentially a verbatim copy of the others.

Answer (score -1):

With `lambda` AND `numpy`. With the help of `lambda` you can write function in one line **AND** `numpy.arange` is like `range()` but it returns an array:-

```
import numpy as np  # Importing numpy module
odd = lambda num: np.arange(1,num*2+1,2)   
odd(10)
```