# dictionary with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

an exercise requires me to write a list comprehension (where the keys should be divisible by 2 and in a range 0-10; the value for each key should be equal to the square of the key) that returns the following output.

`my_dict = { (write code here) for num in (write code here) if (write code here)}`

I have tried the following code but I am obviously making some mistakes.

```
my_dict = {num**2 for num in range(0,10) if float(num/2)==False}
my_dict
```

Could any of you help me understand how it should be done?

thank you very much

Comment: Hi please edit the results generated by your code into your question as text (i.e. not as an image).

Comment: `if float(num/2)==False` Unless `num` is `0`, `num/2` will never be `0`, hence `float(num/2)==False` will never be `True`

Comment: `float(num/2)==False` is **not** how you check for parity. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636640/python-checking-odd-even-numbers-and-changing-outputs-on-number-size

Comment: [PEP-274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#:~:text=This%20PEP%20proposes%20a%20similar,objects%20instead%20of%20list%20objects)

Comment: Note that you want to use `num: num**2` in the first spot.  What you have currently is a `set` comprehension not a `dict` comprehension.

Comment: Errr... Why is this question labelled as duplicate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```py
my_dict = {num : num ** 2 for num in range(10) if num % 2 == 0}
print(my_dict)
```

Output

```
{0: 0, 2: 4, 4: 16, 6: 36, 8: 64}
```